# Non-dependent implicit argument instantiation in Coq's reference manual does not work

Tags: coq, implicit-argument

Consider the following definition

```
Definition foo1 (A : Type) {_ : A} := A.
```

I was wondering whether there is a way to instantiate the non-dependent implicit argument (the `_` here) without using `@`, and I found that the "Explicit applications" section of https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/extensions/implicit-arguments.html mentions that

> To instantiate a non-dependent implicit argument, use the (natural := term) form of arg, where natural is the index of the implicit argument among all non-dependent arguments of the function (implicit or not, and starting from 1) and term is its corresponding explicit term.

However, the following commands fails

```
Check foo1 (1:=2).
Check foo1 nat (1:=2).
```

Moreover, it seems that Coq doesn't accept the grammer because even after adding a `Fail` before the commands, they still fail:

```
Fail Check foo1 (1:=2).
(* => Syntax error: ',' or ')' expected after [term level 200] (in [term]). *)
Fail Check foo1 nat (1:=2).
(* => Syntax error: ',' or ')' expected after [term level 200] (in [term]). *)
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `foo1 nat (1:=2)`?

Comment: This command seems more reasonable, but it still fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a Coq version mismatch. The default online reference manual is for the most recent Coq, which is 8.15.2 at the time of writing. In this version it works. I just tested 8.12.2 and I get the error you describe. You are encouraged to use a recent Coq version, but you can always check the reference manual for older versions from the menu on the lower left corner. For example, [here is the refman for Coq 8.12.2](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/V8.12.2/refman/).

Comment: Thanks. I was using Coq 8.14 and my reference manual was for Coq 8.15. The command "Check foo1 nat (1:=2)." works.